Illustrated children's book about animals travelling world in hot air balloon
A random redditor and I have been separately looking for this book for nearly a decade. We are both Canadian and are looking for a book likely from the 1980s-1990s. It is a large format  (hardcover?) illustrated children's book about a group of animals travelling the world in a hot air balloon or helium balloon. Perhaps 10-20 pages long. The illustrations were very detailed and were full-spread.
The small group of anthropomorphized animals included a lion (the leader of the journey?). There might have also been a kangaroo character...
Each set of pages featured a visit to a different location of the world / to a different biome -- skiing down a mountain, trekking across the desert, farmland, tropical river, and then at the end of the book they travelled to the city (by boat?)and shared different cultural foods around a table.
Thank you for any help!
Original Reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/kp9wtl/a_group_of_animals_travel_around_the_world_in_a/
Original LibraryThing post: https://www.librarything.com/topic/329530#7414001
